# Плавное исчезновение preloader при загрузке страницы

Tags: javascript, css, dom

Пробую реализовать исчезновение след. образом, но opacity сразу становится равным 0

```
window.onload = function() {
        const loader = document.getElementById('page-preloader');
        setInterval(() => loader.style.opacity -= 0.01, 1000);
        if (loader.style.opacity==0) clearInterval();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас изначально св-во `opacity` не задано, соответственно при приведении к числу оно становится равным 0 сразу.

Нужно либо задать свойство `opacity` изначально:

```js
const loader = document.getElementById('page-preloader');
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  loader.style.opacity -= 0.01;
  if (loader.style.opacity==0) clearInterval(interval);
}, 10);
```

```css
#page-preloader{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div style="opacity: 1" id="page-preloader"></div>
```

Либо вводить дополнительную переменную:

```js
const loader = document.getElementById('page-preloader');
let opas = 1;
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  opas -= 0.01;
  loader.style.opacity = opas;
  if (opas == 0) clearInterval(interval);
}, 10);
```

```css
#page-preloader{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-preloader"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое:) добавил стили в тег и все заработало:)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```js
var loader = document.getElementById("loader");
var timer = setInterval(function() {
 loader.style.opacity -= 0.01;
 if (loader.style.opacity == 0)
  clearInterval(timer);
}, 100);
```

```css
#loader {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="loader" style="opacity:1;"></div>
```

Comment: Немного по другому сделал, но все равно спасибо:)

Comment: window.onload = function() {
        const loader = document.getElementById('page-preloader');
        setInterval(() => {
            if(loader.style.opacity==0)clearInterval();
            else loader.style.opacity -= 0.05;
        }, 30);
};

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант сделать на `css`.

```js
$(function() {
  const loader = document.getElementById('page-preloader');
  loader.classList.add('hide-loader');
});
```

```css
#page-preloader {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

#page-preloader.hide-loader {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page-preloader"></div>
```